# get child count and list of records under that

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables which are like below.

```
declare @Table1 table ( ID int, ColName varchar(20), ParentID int)

insert into @Table1
select 1,'Rec1',-1
union
select 2,'Rec2',1
union
select 3,'Rec3',1
union
select 4,'Rec4',2


declare @Table2 table ( ColID int, Name varchar(10),ID int)

insert into @Table2
select 10,'asdf',1
union
select 20,'atsdf',2
union
select 30,'asurdf',3
union
select 40,'ahfsdf',4
union
select 50,'aesdf',2
union
select 60,'asdsfgf',1
union
select 70,'asdfdf',3
```

I want to show top level parent count and under that related records like Parent and Child count. 
The second table data should come under first table parent id, next Child from First table, count of child and second table records, third child, count of Child and related records from second table ..

```
ID Name     Count

1   Rec1    6
10  asdf    NULL
20  atsdf   NULL
2   Rec2    3
50  aesdf   NULL
60  asdsfgf NULL
```

Comment: Do you want to show the parent if there are no child records?

Comment: Why atsdf is under Rec1 and aesdf is under Rec2 when they both have ID 2? Is count 6 correct, should not it be 7? Is the output table complete? If not, can You provide full output?

Comment: In your output, in the first row, is the value 1 from the ID or the ParentID column from table1?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT id,colname,cnt FROM (
SELECT tab1.id,
    tab1.colname,
    COUNT (*) cnt,
    tab1.id sortorder
FROM @Table1 tab1 INNER JOIN @Table2 tab2 ON tab1.id = tab2.id
GROUP BY tab1.id, tab1.colname
UNION ALL
    SELECT colid,
    name,
    NULL,
    id
FROM @Table2
) sub
ORDER BY sortorder, id
```

Comment: This is an exact copy of my first answer before I realized it didn't answer the question, because the `SELECT` does not take the hierarchical properties of the question into account.